# How to do HTTP Session Replication between apache karaf containers?

Tags: distributed-caching, apache-karaf, session-cache

Does anybody know of a way to do http session replication between web apps running in distributed apache karaf OSGi containers?

In this post, http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Pax-web-failover-LoadBalancing-td4029552.html, Jean-Baptiste Onofré says it's not available in apache cellar yet.  Is this capability available anywhere yet?

I've been googling all day and haven't found any options -- Thanks for any help.

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karaf does not have it for pax-web as confirmed by JB in the above post. I am also waiting for him to provide us.

If you are in a hurry

1. You can use Hazelcast (already with Cellar) for session replication.
   Hazelcast supports it and provide HazelcastWM for the same purpose.
2. Jetty does provide session replication and we use jetty as
       servlet-container.You have to check possibility with it.
3. Try on forum for putting Tomcat instead of Jetty.